# How can I upload a uint8 pixel data to Storage on Firebase Functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

`bucket.upload` only accepts file directories and it seems that in functions the method `put` can not be used. With `put`, I think I could be able to upload with new `Uint8Array(data)`. But it does not work with `upload` method.

```
exports.modificarImagen = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {

      const THUMB_PREFIX = 'thumb_';
      const object = event.data; 
      const fileBucket = object.bucket; 
      const filePath = object.name; 
      const contentType = object.contentType; 
      const resourceState = object.resourceState; 
      const metageneration = object.metageneration; 
      const SIZES = [64]; 
      const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
      const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
      const tempIconoPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'icono-amarillo.png');
      const tempPerfilPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'perfil64.jpg');

return bucket.file('images/icono-amarillo.png').download({
  destination: tempIconoPath
}).then(() => {

    bucket.file('images/perfil64.jpg').download({
    destination: tempPerfilPath
    }).then(() => {

      _.each(SIZES, (size) => {

      let newFileName = 'nueva_imagen.png';
      let newFileTemp = path.join(os.tmpdir(), newFileName);
      let newFilePath = `images/${newFileName};`

        sharp(tempIconoPath)
          .flatten()
          .background('#ff6600')
          .overlayWith(tempPerfilPath, { gravity: sharp.gravity.southeast } )
          .sharpen()
          .withMetadata()
          .raw()
          .toBuffer().then(function(outputBuffer) {
                 //here is the problem. outputBuffer is a raw file uint8array and 
                 // storage only allows file path.                  
                  bucket.upload(outputBuffer, {
                      destination: newFilePath
                  }).then(() => { console.log("do another thing"); });
            });
          })//each
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Please explain what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried so far (include your code), and what's not working the way you expect.

Comment: #askfirebase hashtag handler will work only in social media like twitter, not here. You should be more specific with your question with at least some code.

Comment: @Hareesh although it doesn't work on stackoverflow, the Firebase team encourages developers to do it so they can get their questions answered on the show.

Comment: I've also tried with differents lovell/sharp methods like resize or embed and they worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Storage and Sharp along with streams. The following should work:

```
function transform(fileBucket, tempPerfilPath, filePath, newFilePath) {
  const thumbnailUploadStream = fileBucket.file(newFilePath).createWriteStream();

  // Create Sharp pipeline for resizing the image and use pipe to read from bucket read stream
  const pipeline = sharp();
  pipeline
      .flatten()
      .background('#ff6600')
      .overlayWith(tempPerfilPath, { gravity: sharp.gravity.southeast } )
      .sharpen()
      .withMetadata()
      .raw()
      .pipe(thumbnailUploadStream);

  fileBucket.file(filePath).createReadStream().pipe(pipeline);

  const streamAsPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      thumbnailUploadStream.on('finish', resolve).on('error', reject));

  return streamAsPromise.then(() => {
    return console.log('Image created and uploaded successfully');
  });
}
```